# Firestore security rules and Expo not working properly

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, expo

I'm using expo and the firebase web sdk. Everything works fine in my app aslong as I leave the security rules as

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
     allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

However when I try to implement the first rule stated in the docs that should allow full access as long as the user is authenticated, I'm completely locked out from the database, despite being autheneticated inside the app.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

I am using the current users uid to post records to the database so I know I've definitely got some kind of authenticated.

Could the problem be possibly related to react native or even expo?

As far as I'm aware, the second rule stated above should work no problem.

Any inputs appreciated

Comment: I believe it'd be useful to provide the code you're using to read/write from/to the database. And also post the error you're getting

Comment: Same issue here. Everything worked. I could create collections, docs, sub-collections etc. I verified that `firebase.auth().currentUser.uid` is valid prior to request and keep getting permission errors as well.

Comment: I believe this is a problem with the current web sdk @colinwong
I have read reports of people rolling back to a previous SDK and the firestore issues are OK. I have yet to do this on my project however, so I couldn't say for sure yet

Comment: @juicy89 Yes. I rolled back to 4.6.2 and the rules started working again.

Comment: Rolling back to 4.6.2 does indeed fix the issue.